# ggplot selection: should I use 'subset' or 'ifelse' to filter data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, subset

I'm trying to draw two density plots together of two different variables from 2 different datasets.

My datasets are something like these:

**dataset1**

```
Real Wage 1    PPA
1244           105
1577           90
1865           105
1756           105
1634           90
1273           90
2719           105
...            ....
```

**dataset2**

```
Real Wage 2    PPA
1233           105
1588           90
1265           105
1743           105
1224           90
1983           90
2449           105
...            ....
```

And this is my script

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_density( aes( x = dataset1$`Real Wage 1`), fill = "red",  alpha = 0.5)+
  geom_density( aes( x = dataset2$`Real Wage 2`), fill = "blue", alpha = 0.5)+
  theme_classic()
```

It works great, but now I want to plot the observations for `Real Wage 1` and `Real Wage 2` according with specific values of `PPA`

Of course I cannot use the `filter` function because i'm working with two different datasets.
Therefore I've tried to subset each variable

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_density( aes( x = subset(dataset1$`Real Wage 1`, PPA == 105)), fill = "red",  alpha = 0.5)+
  geom_density( aes( x = subset(dataset2$`Real Wage 2`, PPA ==105)), fill = "blue", alpha = 0.5)+
  theme_classic()
```

But it doesn't work because ( I suppose ..) specifing the variable with `$` i'm already excluding all the others and hence the subset doesn't find the `PPA` to apply the logical condition.

I know that it is possible to filter data using the function `ifelse`, but until now everytime i've tried to use it, it hasn't worked ( probably because I'm not able to apply it).

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I am genuinely curious where did you learn to use ggplot in this way? All the documentation I've seen so far is explicit about how to refer to variable names, but you seem to be passing the columns explicitly. To answer your question, I would probably subset the data outside of the ggplot  call, or, possibly, merge the two datasets and plot them in the same plot.

Comment: Try `geom_density(data = subset(dataset1, PPA==105), aes(x = `Real Wage 1`))`

Comment: hi @RomanLuštrik , it is the first time in my life that i'm using ggplot and i'm learning it by myself.... i'm still a bit confusing about it

Comment: hi @AndrewGustar and thank for the reply! It works perfectly... If you write it as an official answer  I can choose it as the best

Comment: Always nice to see new people learning R. In addition to the tips from Allan and Roman, this is my most important tip: Use better names for your columns. Avoid as much as you can to use spaces or special signs except underscore. Avoid capital letters. You can remove spaces easily with `names(df) <- gsub("\\s+","_", names(df))` (this is using a regular expression to replace any number of spaces with an underscore). Why? because spaces and special signs and capital letters are not only more difficult to type/code, but they can also badly mess up your code (create bugs)

Comment: thanks @tjebo for the tips! i'll keep them in mind for the future

Comment: Another option is to use `aes_string`. Please read the documentation for ggplot2 and use the conventions therein. The syntax is a bit different from what we're used to in R. And it's kinda prettier and in place for this particular place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ggplot expects a dataframe to work with, rather than a vector, and you are also using the `subset` function incorrectly.

The way to do this would be to use the following form in your geom_density terms...

```
+ geom_density(data = subset(dataset1, PPA==105), aes(x = `Real Wage 1`), ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

It makes it far easier to work with ggplot if you combine your data into a single long-format data frame. For example, you could combine your two data sets as follows:

```r
library(tidyverse)

combined_data <- dataset2 %>%
  rename(`Real Wage` = `Real Wage 2`) %>%
  bind_rows(rename(dataset1, `Real Wage` = `Real Wage 1`), .id = "dataset") %>%
  mutate(dataset = paste("Real Wage", dataset))

combined_data
#>        dataset Real Wage PPA
#> 1  Real Wage 1      1233 105
#> 2  Real Wage 1      1588  90
#> 3  Real Wage 1      1265 105
#> 4  Real Wage 1      1743 105
#> 5  Real Wage 1      1224  90
#> 6  Real Wage 1      1983  90
#> 7  Real Wage 1      2449 105
#> 8  Real Wage 2      1244 105
#> 9  Real Wage 2      1577  90
#> 10 Real Wage 2      1865 105
#> 11 Real Wage 2      1756 105
#> 12 Real Wage 2      1634  90
#> 13 Real Wage 2      1273  90
#> 14 Real Wage 2      2719 105
```

Note that we have all the "real wage" values in a single column, all the `PPA` values in a single column, and a new column which tells us which of the "real wage" data sets each row belongs to.

This means we only need to filter our data once, and makes the code easier to change. We also get a legend "for free" if we map our dataset column to the `fill` aesthetic. We can specify the specific colors we want using `scale_fill_manual`. Doing it this way keeps the legend and plot working together nicely:

```r
ggplot(filter(combined_data, PPA == 105), aes(x = `Real Wage`, fill = dataset)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("gold", "deepskyblue")) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20)
```

[image]

Note also that rather than filtering on `PPA` and creating one plot for each, you can use `facet_grid` and do them all at once if your data is set up this way:

```r
ggplot(combined_data, aes(`Real Wage`, fill = dataset)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("gold", "deepskyblue")) +
  facet_grid(.~PPA) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>